# Delphi: Webbrowser.Document -> check existence of Element by ID

Tags: delphi, element, twebbrowser

I've got a TWebbrowser Component and some Buttons doing stuff. This works well so far, but during one procedure I want to click on a button on the website to display additional Information, which should be clicked on as well.

So I've got this:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('linkDtlC0-0').Click();
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('linkDtlC0-1').Click();
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('linkDtlC0-2').Click();
```

Then I have to click a Button on the website to display the next three elements to click on. No Problem so far, but after clicking the button the site takes a few Seconds to display the three elements.

My Problem:
When I try to click the elements immediately after clicking the Button clearly it results in an error saying that there is no element (yet) to click on with this name. Of course I could make my program wait a few seconds (more) just be be sure and then try to click, but I do not want to waste time so my question is:
Is there a way to check, whether an element (by name) exists on the Document inside the TWebbrowser?

Comment: Handle the `OnDocumentComplete` event and check there if `pDisp = TWebBrowser(Sender).ControlInterface` (that means the document is "ready"). If so, start traversing your document. To check if certain element exists you can simply check if the reference returned by `GetElementByID` is `Assigned`.

Comment: This does also not work. Maybe your answer is right, but I encountered some suspicious behaviour of the TWebbrowser: I clicked the button manually and waited some seconds until the desired elements appeared. Then I listed all the IDs using `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.All.Item(i).ID);` and there appeared the first three elements as normal, but the next (fourth) item was still not listed there, although my regular browsers (chrome and firefox) were telling me, that the fourth element should be there. My TWebbrowser seems to ignore the changes on the site for some unknown reason.

Comment: The site sometimes uses the first digit '0' three times, but sometimes also four or five times before increasing the first digit.. This was not so obvious to me, because as I tested the site with some random data it was always counting up as I thought it would do this every time, but that is not the case. Sorry for asking this question, but I thought this was an issue of the TWebbrowser component. –

Comment: I rollled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to edit your post and add [solved] and the solution. You can answer your own question if you'd like, but you have to do so properly by doing so in the form of an answer in the space provided for it below. See [Can I answer my own questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: You already know the answer to your question - `getElementById`. It will tell you if a given named element exists or not. That is not your real question. Your real question is how to detect when new objects become available. For that, I would start a short timer (not a loop, unless you call `Application.ProcessMessages` in it, which is not advisable) and call `getElementById` until it returns a valid object, then move on. DON'T call `Click` prematurely! Using an exception handler to detect existence is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, whether an element exists:

```
uses
  MSHTML;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
var
  Element: IHTMLElement;
begin
  if pDisp = TWebBrowser(ASender).ControlInterface then
  begin
    Element := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementById('linkDtlC0-3');
    if Assigned(Element) then
      Element.click;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: No. This is not what you're supposed to do. It can be as simple as [this](https://pastebin.com/5dMieMuh).